# Conditional format Google sheet when criteria is matched from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google sheet that contains two sheets. One ("`Actual`") has a range of values under different day headings(Sunday, Monday, Tuesday .....), which is updated every day. Therefore the days in the column headers change day-on-day, along with the values under each heading. The columns are `E:K` in both sheets, the headers being in row 1 of each, the values in row 2. In the other sheet ("`Capacity`") is a static list of values under the days of the week.

I want to use conditional formatting to highlight the values in "`Actual`" if they are higher than the values under the corresponding day in "`Capacity`". I know to use the `INDIRECT` function to reference another sheet and can write a custom formula to match the day, but I'm struggling to write one that first matches the day of the week, then checks against the value.

Unfortunately I'm unable to share documents outside of my organisation, otherwise, I'd provide a copy. I appreciate this may make it difficult to help me.

Comment: load your scenario: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udiqAT5eyxTZCabRxkcuk58ac3wCHA5r0wY8qHgVgXQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: Have added some values to Actual. These, along with the days in the header will update daily though. So tomorrow, E1 will be Friday, with new values underneath etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=HLOOKUP(E$1:K$1,INDIRECT("Capacity!E1:K2"),2,0)
```

[image: 0]

### **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udiqAT5eyxTZCabRxkcuk58ac3wCHA5r0wY8qHgVgXQ/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: That works in principle and I've marked the answer as correct based on what I asked. However if more than one row had data in in both sheets, how would that work? Column D has unique references that match in both sheets, and each reference has a different figure against them. Also is there a way to amend the formula to highlight the cell is the value is greater than 10% for example?

Comment: for 10%: `=HLOOKUP(E$1:K$1,INDIRECT("Capacity!E1:K2"),2,0)+10%` and for more rows not rly sure how you imagine it to work out

Comment: I've worked it out. I was forgetting to change the row selection from 2 to 3 and so on depending on which which to lookup against.